# Requesting POST in Java using HttpUrlConnection is returning "propertyValue: false"

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

**What i want?**

I'm developing a Java application using the HttpUrlConnection library to send a POST and return the response from the site.

**What is going on?**

The code does not display syntax errors but when I execute it, it prints the message "propertyValue: false" even though I have not put any command to print anything.

**What i need?**

I need to know where this error is (propertyValue: false), because as I said, it does not show as if it had an error.
source:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            String target = "http://google.com";
            String parameters = "contentOfPost";
            URL url = new URL(target);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            try{
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", parameters + Integer.toString(parameters.getBytes().length));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.google.com");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(parameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            InputStream in =  conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line=null;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            } catch (IOException e){}
        }
}
```

> Out: propertyValue:false

Comment: Can you show the contents negotiated?

Comment: Didn't understand you, Roman C. What do you mean with "Show the contents negotiated"?

Comment: Please add some info on your context: How do you run it, where is the message printed, ...? If I run your code (and add `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch block, I get _HTTP 405: method not allowed_  which is something to be expected.

Comment: I'm runing at AIDE v.3.2.2 (app). This "error" is printed on console screen.